# Shearing in 2D affine transformations

Tags: geometry, computer-vision, affinetransform, scikit-image

I was looking at some code in python skimage toolkit regarding representing affine transformations in 2D and there is an `AffineTransform` class which is defined as:

```
Parameters
----------
matrix : (3, 3) array, optional
    Homogeneous transformation matrix.
scale : (sx, sy) as array, list or tuple, optional
    Scale factors.
rotation : float, optional
    Rotation angle in counter-clockwise direction as radians.
shear : float, optional
    Shear angle in counter-clockwise direction as radians.
translation : (tx, ty) as array, list or tuple, optional
    Translation parameters.
```

I notice that the shearing only takes one parameter (shearing angle in counter-clockwise direction). However, why should this not be two parameters? I can shear in x AND in y direction. How come these two operations map into one free parameter in 2D?

Answer (score 1):

Currently in the code we have, for the transformation matrix:

```
            [sx * math.cos(rotation), -sy * math.sin(rotation + shear), 0],
            [sx * math.sin(rotation),  sy * math.cos(rotation + shear), 0],
            [                      0,                                0, 1]
```

I wonder if this is indeed the most intuitive way to specify shear.  I have opened an issue: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/1779

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if you would be kind enough to explain the algebra behind it.

Comment: I agree that this is not the most common way of expressing shear.  Feel free to open an issue on that.  In the mean time, you can use the more generic ProjectiveTransform.